# R: Functions Arbitrarily Returning Functions Based on Input

Tags: r, function, pointers, input

I'm using the nloptr package in R for non-linear optimization. I am trying to set up some generic wrapper functions that can easily switch between different optimization problems based on some characters.

I tried to create a simple example of the issue I'm having. Consider the following functions (producing a list containing the value of the objective and gradient),

```
f_quadratic <- function(x, a1=0) {
    list("objective" = a1 * x^2, "gradient" = a1 * 2 * x)
}
f_cubic <- function(x, a1=0, a2=1) {
    list("objective" = a1 + a2 * x^3, "gradient" = a2 * 3 * x ^ 2)
}
```

One way to switch between them is (coutresy of @alexis_laz)

```
f_test <- function(f, ...) {
    function(x) {
        match.fun(f)(x, ...)
    }
}
```

So given

```
x <- 2
a1 <- 4
a2 <- 3
```

I could run

```
f <- "f_quadratic"
g <- f_test(f, a1=a1)
g(x)
```

or

```
f <- "f_cubic"
g <- f_test(f, a1=a1, a2=a2)
g(x)
```

and get the results. The g function would ultimately get passed to the eval_f argument in nloptr. However, this does not work

```
f <- "f_quadratic"
g <- f_test(f, a1=a1, a2=a2)
g(x)
```

since a2 is not needed for f_quadratic.

How can I adjust this for arbitrary inputs in a way that still works with nloptr?

Comment: Perhaps you're -somehow- looking for `match.fun`? E.g. `testf = function(f) match.fun(f); f = "f_cubic"; testf(f)`

Comment: Appears to work perfect, thanks. You could probably write that up as an answer.

Comment: @alexis_laz As a follow up, I am able to call testf(f) as testf(f)(x, a) or if I use that list above as do.call(testf(f), y). Is there any way to do anything like testf(f)(y). I tried playing around with some stuff with alist and substitute, but didn't have much luck. Or something like unlist that puts the arguments of y into testf(f)(here) without do.call?

Comment: Hm, I can't think of something like that as possible right now. As a workaround, though, you could change your function to accept `...` arguments and operate on a `list(...)` i.e. use the `do.call` inside the function. E.g.: `fcub2 = function(...) { args = list(...); if(length(args) == 1) args = args[[1]]; do.call(f_cubic, args) }`. Then, `f = "fcub2"; testf(f)(x, a); testf(f)(y)`.

Comment: The functions I'm writing are for the optimization package nloptr. It does not let you use functions that take elipsis as arguments, for whatever reason.

Comment: The other thing I was thinking about is if I adjust f_cubic to be something like a1 + a2 * x^3 so it takes (x, a1, a2) as arguments, then to produce another function that only takes x as an argument but produces the same result. Some sort of nested function or something.

Comment: I can't think of what of a problem might arise useing `...` but the "fcub2" function, in my comment above, pretty much follows your last thinking. Of course, instead of `...` you could use _one_ argument as a "list" an use `do.call` in the wrapper function. E.g `fcub3 = function(X) do.call(f_cubic, X)` and then, `f = "fcub3"; testf(f)(y)`. `testf(f)(x, a)` won't work now, though, while with "fcub2" works.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's a problem either, but the package's main function won't work if I pass ellipsis. Something like
f_test <- function(f, ...) {
 function(x) {
  match.fun(f)(x, ...)
 }
}
works. And then I would just call g <- f_test("f_cubic", a1, a2), then g(x). But then I can't use that in nloptr.

Comment: Actually I may have spoken too soon. It does seem to let me call g(x) in nloptr since I have removed the dots.

Comment: From `?nloptr` if I run their example "res", but using `eval_f2 = function(...) do.call(eval_f, list(...))` as the "eval_f" argument, seems to work, (unless I'm missing something). Nevertheless, if you don't manage to work it out, editing your question with the new specific problem so that it becomes 'newly active' (or, perhaps, asking a new one) will get someone's attention; I bet there has to be a workaround.

Comment: Now I'm all confused as to why my problem wasn't working before. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Ah, okay, the problem is that in nloptr you have to pass all the optional variables specifically. So if I adjust the eval_f in that example to include some variable a1, then I have to add a1 to the function call for the gradient and for the call to nloptr. I can still use your eval_f2 this way. However, if I replace the a1 in the call to nloptr with ellipsis, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Ha, now it's my turn to be confused! I, really, think you should edit the question with an example problem. People see all those comments and give up hoping on answering such a "negotiating" question :-). Also, since it turned out to be a different problem than the starting one, you may consider asking a new question?

Comment: Good idea, I'll edit it.

Comment: I think what I'm going to do is just edit it and then answer it. I was worried about a performance hit to a different technique, but I think it's not as big as I had thought.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to create a new function

```
f_test_2 <- function(f, arg_f) {
    function(x) {
        do.call(f, c(list(x), arg_f))
    }
}
```

and then run

```
arg_f0 <- list(a1 = a1, a2 = a2)
f <- "f_quadratic"
arg_f <- arg_f0[names(arg_f0) %in% names(formals(f))]
g <- f_test_2(f, arg_f)
g(x)
```

There is a modest performance hit by taking this approach, but my estimates put it on the order of about 3% for a more sophisticated sample problem.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, if you define "f_quadratic" with an extra `...` argument, the last piece of code in your question works. "a2" is just left unused since R doesn't evaluate arguments until they're needed and -in this case- "a2" is never needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check if that works with npoptr (tomorrow).

Comment: It looks like that approach works, but I didn't notice any speed up. With microbenchmark, the median is roughly the same in either case. There are some differences on the other results microbenchmark produces, but they are less favorable for the approach you suggested, if anything.